AES-256 file encryption in c#
I recently needed to write a portion of code to encrypt file to AES-256 in C# language.
Since I did not find ready implementations of it, apart from string encryption, and since I'm very far from cryptography field, I'm worried that it's insecure. Can you please revise if my encryption code is secure?
I checked it works for Windows and Ubuntu, however I will also need to support Android.
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(@"AES-256 File Encryption and Decryption
Usage:
app encrypt sourceFile encryptedFile password
app decrypt encryptedFile decryptedFile password

");

        string input = args[0];
        string inputFile = args[1];
        string outputFile = args[2];
        string password = args[3];

        if (input == "encrypt")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypting");
            EncryptFile(inputFile, outputFile, password);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
        else if (input == "decrypt")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypting");
            DecryptFile(inputFile, outputFile, password);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }

    static void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password)
    {
        const int version = 1;
        const int keySize = 256;
        const int createKeyIterations = 1000;
        const string hashAlgorithm = "SHA512";

        using var fsInput = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var fsOutput = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.KeySize = keySize;
        var keySalt = CreateSalt(aes.KeySize / 8);
        var ivSalt = CreateSalt(aes.BlockSize / 8);

        using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fsOutput, Encoding.ASCII, true))
        {
            aes.Key = CreateKey(password, keySalt, createKeyIterations, hashAlgorithm);
            aes.IV = CreateKey(password, ivSalt, createKeyIterations, hashAlgorithm);

            binaryWriter.Write(version);
            binaryWriter.Write(aes.KeySize);
            binaryWriter.Write(aes.BlockSize);
            binaryWriter.Write(createKeyIterations);
            binaryWriter.Write(hashAlgorithm);
        }

        fsOutput.Write(keySalt);
        fsOutput.Write(ivSalt);
        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        fsInput.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
    }

    static void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile, string password)
    {
        using var fsInput = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fsInput, Encoding.ASCII, true);
        var version = binaryReader.ReadInt32();

        if (version != 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported version");

        using var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.KeySize = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        aes.BlockSize = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        int iterations = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        var hashAlgorithm = binaryReader.ReadString();

        var keySalt = new byte[aes.KeySize / 8];
        fsInput.ReadExactly(keySalt);
        aes.Key = CreateKey(password, keySalt, iterations, hashAlgorithm);

        var ivSalt = new byte[aes.BlockSize / 8];
        fsInput.ReadExactly(ivSalt);
        aes.IV = CreateKey(password, ivSalt, iterations, hashAlgorithm);

        using var fsOutput = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        fsInput.CopyTo(cryptoStream);
    }

    static byte[] CreateSalt(int bytesLength)
    {
        return RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(bytesLength);
    }

    static byte[] CreateKey(string password, byte[] salt, int iterations, string hashAlgorithm)
    {
        HashAlgorithmName algorithm;
        switch (hashAlgorithm)
        {
            case "SHA512":
                algorithm = HashAlgorithmName.SHA512;
                break;
            // Compatibility: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#sha-3
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(hashAlgorithm));
        }

        using var keyGenerator = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations, algorithm);
        return keyGenerator.GetBytes(salt.Length);
    }
}

Parts that I'm worried

I have to prepend salts inside the encrypted content. Probably it can use zero salt in this case at all. But over internet they write it's secure.
SHA512 hash algorithm used to create IV, Key is SHA 2 version. But mine Windows 11 does not support version 3 at the moment as well as Android and I don't understand should I investigate some open-source libraries or be ok with SHA v2 512. Though .Net compatibility list is not promising https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#sha-3
Default encryption mode is CBC, which means each next encrypted block will somehow use the previous encrypted block for IV change. But I saw other encryption modes available for .Net and I don't know why they are there and why not to leave just one that works better for the majority of use cases.
I don't know how to select iterations. Since performance of computations increases, it means my algorithm needs to be reviewed year after year? Or there're some existing approaches to write code for decades without changes, my thoughts are that iterations count should be calculated upon usage on particular device of user for 1 second of computations.

Any other comments are also appreciated.

Biggest drawback of this kind of code is of course the existance of countless file encryption tools readily available, including openssl command line.

Thanks @MaartenBodewes . Currently I'm using 7-zip for encryption of files. And I was exploring options of Android and there're no 7-zip binaries for it. When I started to explore other software - its not really a cross platform and majority of it is not code reviewed or last updated years ago. Also there's trust issue. Same btw with high level libraries.

The questions

I have to preprend salts inside the encrypted content. Probably it can use zero salt in this case at all. But over internet they write its secure.

Not sure what your source is, but salt is a parameter that can be publicly available. Sometimes it is used together with a secret parameter that can be e.g. integrated into the code called a pepper. That might make (combined) brute force & dictionary attacks - and the attacks based on those attacks such as rainbow tables - less likely.

SHA512 hash algorithm used to create IV, Key is SHA 2 version. But mine Windows 11 does not support version 3 at the moment as well as Android and I don't understand should I investigate some open-source libraries or be ok with SHA v2 512. Though .Net compatibility list is not promising https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#sha-3

It is absolutely not necessary to use SHA-3 for the PBKDF2 function that you are using (the algorithm implemented by the badly named Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

Default encryption mode is CBC, which means each next encrypted block will somehow use previous encrypted block for IV change. But I saw other encryption modes available for .Net and I don't know why they are there and why not to leave just one that works better for majority of use cases.

I'm not sure what one has to do with the other. How CBC mode works is clearly indicated on Wikipedia. CBC is secure for encryption, but it doesn't offer integrity or authenticity of the data. For that you'll also need to use a message authentication code such as HMAC or an authenticated cipher such as GCM.
The disadvantage of GCM is that it is not a perfect mode for file encryption as it, for instance, has restrictions on the amount of data it can encrypt securely.

I don't know how to select iterations. Since performance of computations increases, it means my algorithm needs to be reviewed year after year?

Well, that's maybe a bit much, but yes, computational advances are certainly a problem when using password based encryption. If an adversary can have the ciphertext (and that's generally assumed, or you would not have to encrypt) then they are able to mount an offline, parallel attack, or store ciphertext to be decrypted in the future.
Best is to avoid using passwords. If you do need to use password, then certainly don't stop at a high iteration count; also require the user to use a really strong password, for instance. Indicating the estimated security strength of the password in bits would for instance be a good measure to take. Of course, such measures are hard to program.

Or there're some existing approaches to write code for decades without changes, my thoughts are that iterations count should be calculated upon usage on particular device of user for 1 second of computations.

No, decades is a bit much. Remember that commercial encryption is just over half a century old by now. It's a pretty new field that is constantly evolving. Computers and quantum computers are also a thing.
If 1s of computations is enough depends on what you are trying to protect, who you are protecting against. But with a strong password of say 70-80 bits in strength is probably alright.
The protocol.
There should be a separate file that explains the protocol. Just programming something without explaining the protocol will come back to haunt you.
Kudos for including a version number. That makes future upgrades much easier.
Storing the parameter sizes in the header is slightly dangerous as an adversary may change those, but that's not a big issue. I'd authenticated them when using a MAC or authenticated cipher though.
Calling CreateKey(password, ivSalt, createKeyIterations, hashAlgorithm) again for generation of the IV wastes cycles, cycles that an adversary won't need to spend to find a password (finding a password / key even if the IV is unknown is about as easy as if it is unknown). Instead the ivSalt might as well just be used as an IV.
Otherwise this is just password based encryption using CBC. There isn't much to say. CBC is fine for encrypting data in place. Since different keys, salts and IV's are used the keys and data are pretty well protected, even if the password is reused (of course there are plenty of reasons not do reuse passwords besides that).
The design
Stream handling seems generally fine. I'm happy to see a streams used in the correct direction (encryption uses writes to the CryptoStream, while decryption uses reads). You are using using so automatic resource management is employed; the files are closed when the variables go out of scope.
One problem is that IO errors are basically ignored, which may leave you with partially written (but correctly closed) files. I'd at least document to the user of these functions that they can be thrown and that this may lead to partial files being written.
A big problem is the handling of parameters, and especially the password. I'd highly recommend using a CLI parsing library to allow parameters to be explained, for instance. Having to input the password on the command line is a clear violation of security best practices.
In general the class design seems to be OK. I personally don't like that the files are passed as Strings though; I'd just pass the files themselves so that the detection etc. of the files can be performed by the caller. I't also a bit strange to use Strings for filenames after complaining that many libs simply are performing encryption on strings.
Personally I'd rather go for a password based key derivation function (PBKDF) that is also memory hard, such as one of the Argon variants. Those do however not exists directly in the .NET environment though.
The code
The variable naming and such seems to be fine; variable identifiers clearly show the purpose of the variables for instance. Calling your program Program ... well, you might want to think about a name.
CreateKey seems is too generic for me. A name like DeriveKeyFromPassword is still generic as it doesn't show how this is performed, but at least it would more clearly specify the purpose of the function.
Aes.Create() is used instead of a constructor. This is great, as this will likely mean you'll get the default implementation available in the .NET environment. This will likely be one that implements AES natively, which in turn means that it will probably use hardware accelerated & protected processor instructions (e.g. AES-NI on x64).
As indicated before, I'd like some more error handling. As a user I'd be pissed if I would get something like a stacktrace instead of "done". And as programmer I'd like some kind of response value other than 0 indicating what kind of error occurred.

Thanks for giving me feedback. Especially about SHAv3, I'll definietely read about HMAC, because integrity is also needed and i was thinking about separate hash SHAv2 512, but if its included, then why not.... Regading console tool - i will use it with streams. I make it as console to check interoperability on different OSes, because many crypto libs cannot decryppt whats encrypted on windows on linux, i was mad discovering it.

Of course I won't argue against creating a console for initial testing, but I find that in the end I'd write Unit tests. That's probably after a review or two though, so yeah :)
